# Outlook - Reply To All disconnects?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, connection

Had Exchange die on me last week, and had to rebuild the box.

Upon rebuilding, everything seems to work as normal except when I hit Reply To All; Outlook disconnects from Exchange temporarily.
I've never seen this, and I can't seem to properly search for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it disconnect after 1 email, before 1 email.. or after n emails?

Comment: As soon as I press "reply to all" a notice says Outlook can't connect to Exchange.  Reply works fine, even I manually add the addresses.

Comment: possibly something corrupt with your client- can you replicate the problem on another outlook on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by bad permissions on our Exchange GAL.  Try recreating your Offline Address Book, and checking the permissions on your GAL.  Why it affected Reply To All is still beyond me.  YMMV.